# How to arrange many <div> elements side by side with no wrap

Tags: html, css, css-float

There are three div elements side by side in a container div, with smaller width than children total 
width. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SasDh/) you can find the Fiddle of the case:

I want to make container div scroll horizontally in order to show other children.

How can I arrange children not to wrap inside container div?
It scroll vertically now, I want it to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Change `float: left` to `display: inline-block;` and add `white-space: nowrap` to the container.

Comment: And be careful not have whitespace in the markup :). [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SasDh/4/) of this solution.

Comment: Note:  This solution will not work of the divs actually contain content:  http://jsfiddle.net/Jnz7e/

Comment: @Jason Add `vertical-align:top` to the blocks.

Comment: In case you have many div in some other place in body than try this without float:left.

Comment: @kapa does .pContiner div { display: inline-block; } affect all divs that are a child of pContiner or only the first level?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts It affects all descendants. If you only need the first level (direct children), use the `>` selector. [Suggested reading: CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information.3A_Selectors_based_on_relationships)

Comment: Previously mine was not working because I have both float: left and display: inline-block at the same time. Removing float: left is the solution for my case :)

Answer (score 3):

You need a another `div` within the scrolling `div` that has a total width equal to all of the widths of it's children.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdavenport/SasDh/2/

There was already an extra `div` there so I used that one

Bonus: To get rid of the vertical scroll bar use `overflow-y: hidden`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdavenport/SasDh/3/

Comment: Inner div.width is unknown, child divs are appending dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

The `<span>` tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.
[(source)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp)